# Can I somehow "instrument" Graphics.TBitmapCanvas with overriden GetPixel/SetPixel methods, which are specific to TBitmap's canvas?

Tags: delphi, vcl

As we know, working with `TBitmap`'s pixels (`Bitmap.Canvas.Pixels[X,Y]`) is very slow in the out-of-box VCL. This has been caused by getter and setter of `Pixels` property inherited from `TCanvas`, which encapsulates general WinGDI DC object and is not specific to MemDC of bitmap.

For the DIB section-based bitmaps (`bmDIB`) a [well-known workaround](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/ImageProcessing/Scanline.htm) exists, however I do not see the way to integrate the proper getter/setter in the VCL TBitmap class (besides direct modification of library code, which proven to be real *pain in the stern* when it comes to compiling against different VCL versions).

Please advise if there is some hackish way to reach `TBitmapCanvas` class and inject overriden methods into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure it could be done more elegantly, but here's what you ask for implemented using a class helper to crack the private members:

```
unit BitmapCanvasCracker;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Windows, Graphics;

implementation

procedure Fail;
begin
  raise EAssertionFailed.Create('Fixup failed.');
end;

procedure PatchCode(Address: Pointer; const NewCode; Size: Integer);
var
  OldProtect: DWORD;
begin
  if not VirtualProtect(Address, Size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OldProtect) then begin
    Fail;
  end;
  Move(NewCode, Address^, Size);
  FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess, nil, 0);
  if not VirtualProtect(Address, Size, OldProtect, @OldProtect) then begin
    Fail;
  end;
end;

type
  PInstruction = ^TInstruction;
  TInstruction = packed record
    Opcode: Byte;
    Offset: Integer;
  end;

procedure RedirectProcedure(OldAddress, NewAddress: Pointer);
var
  NewCode: TInstruction;
begin
  NewCode.Opcode := $E9;//jump relative
  NewCode.Offset := NativeInt(NewAddress)-NativeInt(OldAddress)-SizeOf(NewCode);
  PatchCode(OldAddress, NewCode, SizeOf(NewCode));
end;

type
  TBitmapCanvas = class(TCanvas)
    // you need to implement this class
  end;

type
  TBitmapHelper = class helper for TBitmap
    function NewGetCanvas: TCanvas;
    class procedure Patch;
  end;

function TBitmapHelper.NewGetCanvas: TCanvas;
begin
  if Self.FCanvas = nil then
  begin
    Self.HandleNeeded;
    if Self.FCanvas = nil then
    begin
      Self.FCanvas := TBitmapCanvas.Create;
      Self.FCanvas.OnChange := Self.Changed;
      Self.FCanvas.OnChanging := Self.Changing;
    end;
  end;
  Result := Self.FCanvas;
end;

class procedure TBitmapHelper.Patch;
begin
  RedirectProcedure(@TBitmap.GetCanvas, @TBitmap.NewGetCanvas);
end;

initialization
  TBitmap.Patch;

end.
```

Include this unit in your project and the `TBitmap` class will be patched so that its `GetCanvas` method redirects to `NewGetCanvas` and allows you to implement your own `TCanvas` subclass.

I don't think the code will work if you are using runtime packages but to sort that out you just need to use more capable hooking code.

Comment: This method of detouring works just fine with runtime packages. What does not work is when you have different modules **without** runtime packages (in that case you need the patch unit in every project).

Comment: @StefanGlienke That's not a common scenario and one that is trivial to resolve

Comment: Thanks for fresh idea. However, I'm stuck with reimplementing `TBitmapCanvas` under my controls, since it depends on the other private `Graphics` symbols, like `BitmapCanvasList` and `TBitmapImage`. Currently I do not see the way to isolate them.

Comment: The really hacky way is to put Graphics.pas into your project, and modify the code in the implementation section.